# Problem displaying MVC webgrid in a webform project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, webgrid

I have added MVC files/folders to an existing Webforms project. In the References, i have added the reference to 'System.Web.Helpers.dll'.
Now, while trying to display the Webgrid, i am getting the following message:

Message=Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRenderer'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
Source=System.Web.Helpers.

Most of the fixes that i have seen so far for this kind of error state the following solutions, and i have already tried all of them:

1. No Security tab in the properties of the my project, so unchecking "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" is not an option.
2. Have tried to comment out the reference to 'System.Web.Helpers' in the web.config.
3. The following line already does not exist in my AssemblyInfo.cs file, so removing this line is also not an option. [assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]

Looks like the problem is because, i have added MVC files in a Webforms project,  but am wondering if there is any fix for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After i updated my System.Web.Helpers.dll to version 3.0.0.0 and also copied its xml file in the reference folder, it's working for me now.